# Projection of a four dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C^3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $H:=\lbrace y_1=y_2=0\rbrace$, where $z_j = x_j +\sqrt{-1}y_j$, $j = 1; 2; 3$ be a four dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C^3}$.

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C^3}$ be holomorphic curve not identically zero ($f\neq 0$). Let $\pi:\mathbb{C^3}\setminus\lbrace0\rbrace\rightarrow \mathbb{C} P^2$ the canonical projection to the complex projective space $\mathbb{C} P^2$.

Question: if $f$ avoids $H$, must $\pi(f)$ avoid $\pi(H)$?.

Note: $\pi(H)$ is given by the closure of $\lbrace [1,Z_1,Z_2]\mid Z_2 ~ \text{is a real multiple of} ~Z_1\rbrace$.

Comment: I'm pretty confused by several aspects of this question. Let's start at the beginning: what do you take for $\pi:\Bbb C^3\to \Bbb CP^2$ as your "canonical projection"? (If you want to take $(a,b,c)\mapsto [a:b:c]$, this is not a map because it doesn't send $(0,0,0)$ anywhere, and there are more problems down the line.)

Comment: Yes you are right. our canonical projection $\pi:\mathbb{C}\setminus\lbrace 0\rbrace\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^2$. and we assume that our $f$ is not identically zero.

Comment: @jalledabdessami Do you mean $\mathbb C^3_{\mathbb R}$ ? I'm a beginner.

Comment: I mean a real four dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}^3$. here $\mathbb{C}^3$ can be identified to $\mathbb{R}^6$.

Comment: @jalledabdessami, yes, thanks! We used this notation so I wanted to check if I understand the post.

Comment: solved problem. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Consider the curve $f:\Bbb C\to \Bbb C^3$ given by $z\mapsto (z,i,i)$. Clearly this avoids $H$, but includes the point $(i,i,i)$ which maps to the same point as $(1,1,1)$ under $\pi$.

I would also caution you that the map $\pi$ behaves strangely on sets which are not stable under the scaling action by $\Bbb C^*$ in $\Bbb C^3\setminus 0$. Perhaps you have a good reason for pursuing this, but if I ended up thinking about something like this I'd be curious about whether I was on the right track. If this is a case of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), you may be better served by asking about your original problem.

Comment: yes your counter-example is completely true. in fact in this case what i did is false because this is a very important condition so that my theorem be true. in an other hand you can find my real problem in my next answer.

Comment: KReiser can we talk by e-mail, I have very interesting question. thanks to you.

Comment: @jalledabdessami It is inappropriate to post your other/original problem as an answer to this question. Instead, you should post it as a new problem.

Comment: yes you are right. i will post it immediately. i tried many times in this problem , hope i can find a solution so that i can finich my paper. Thanks to you